# php variable from random list

Tags: php, include, echo, shuffle

I am trying to include a piece of text from a config file into a php file that generates a random number of tags from a seperate list of tags.

**Code to generate the tags :**

```
    <?php
include '../config/filenames.php';
$keywords = explode(",", file_get_contents("taglist.php"));
shuffle($keywords);
$keys = array();
foreach (array_slice($keywords, 0, 20) as $word) {
    $word = trim($word);
    $keys[] =  $word;
}
echo join(',', $keys);

?>
```

**This is the taglist :**

```
<a href='<?php echo $filename_a?>'>test</a>,
<a href='<?php echo $filename_a?>'>test2</a>,
<a href='<?php echo $filename_a?>'>test3</a>,
<a href='<?php echo $filename_a?>'>test4</a>
```

For some reason it is not including the $filename_a. It looks like the result of the random data is not parsing the php, but simply printing the piece of php code rather then the result of it.

Can someone help ?

Comment: Try to change the single quotes into double quotes " '

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately it doesnt work